# Load flexslider in easytabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, flexslider

I am trying to load flexslider in easytabs. I have two flexsliders on the page. One in under photos which loads with the page and the other is under Features. The flexslider on the Features tab will not load because it is initially hidden.

I am looking for some js code to execute the second flexslider when the tab is clicked.

Any help is appreciated

Note: I have already made adjustments and confirmed that both flexsliders work on the page without tabs.

I went with pikachoose instead of flexslider and it worked.

Comment: I don't really see a visible issue on that page .. what is the problem?

Comment: If you go to the Features tab there should be another flexslider there but it does not load because it is initially hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for what I wanted to do.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        animationLoop: false,
        prevText: '',
        nextText: '',
        controlNav: false,
        keyboard: false,
        slideshow: false,
        start: function(){
            // This is your easytabs install
            $('.tab-container').easytabs({
                updateHash: false,
                animate: false
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Basically it only initialises easytabs when flexslider is done.